# How may I pause/resume an audio .swf with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created with Flash an audio swf file which contains a single mp3 song; nothing else. Hence, there is no ActionScript. I 've embedded it in an html file with Dreamweaver and I've got the following code:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="20" height="20"   
id="FlashID"     title="test">
<param name="movie" value="struggle.swf">
<param name="quality" value="high">
<param name="wmode" value="opaque">
<param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0">
<!-- This param tag prompts users with Flash Player 6.0 r65 and higher to download the latest  
version of Flash Player. Delete it if you don’t want users to see the prompt. -->
<param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf">
<!-- Next object tag is for non-IE browsers. So hide it from IE using IECC. -->
<!--[if !IE]>-->
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="struggle.swf" width="20" height="20">
<!--<![endif]-->
<param name="quality" value="high">
<param name="wmode" value="opaque">
<param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0">
<param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf">
<!-- The browser displays the following alternative content for users with Flash Player 6.0 and  
older. -->
<div>
  <h4>Content on this page requires a newer version of Adobe Flash Player.</h4>
  <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img 
src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe 
Flash player" width="112" height="33" /></a></p>
</div>
<!--[if !IE]>-->
</object>
<!--<![endif]-->
</object>
```

So far, so good. The song plays every time my page is loaded.Now, I want to have a button inside my html file which will control the swf. Press once pauses the song, press again resumes. I've tried a lot of methods, however none of them works.For example:

```
window.document.flashID.Play();
```

does not work...
Also, the jQuery SWFObject Plugin did not work (perhaps it is only for movies?). And some other attempts did not succeed. Please any ideas for I am so tired with that.

Comment: There are dozens of solid flash player javascript libraries out there.  Have you tried any of them?

Comment: Wish you were more specific. It is not so easy as you may think...

Comment: Have you tried googling `javascript flash player` or similar.  You will get page after page of options.